# How to Check/Uncheck jquery-ui checkboxradio programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, checkbox

I am trying to check/uncheck a `jquery-ui` `checkboxradio` widget programatically (i.e. without using the mouse).  I've tried all manner of things but not joy.  To reproduce the issue, choose a blank html page with just `jquery` and `jquery-ui` script tags and then create the widget dynamically:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Blank</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

After the page loads, I hit `F12` to bring up dev-tools and enter the following commands to get a minimal `jquery-ui` checkbox:

```
$container = $("<div>")
$container.append($("<label for='chkbox'>"))
$container.append($("<input type='checkbox' id='chkbox'>"))
$container.appendTo('body')
$('#chkbox').checkboxradio()
```

The checkbox is unchecked by default. Lets try to check it:

```
$('#chkbox').attr('checked', true) // nope
$('#chkbox').checkboxradio('refresh') // nope
$('#chkbox').attr('checked', false)
$('#chkbox').prop('checked', true) // nope
$('#chkbox').prop('checked', false)
$('#chkbox').addClass('ui-checkboxradio-checked') // not this either
$('#chkbox').removeClass('ui-checkboxradio-checked')
$('#chkbox').checkboxradio('option', 'classes.ui-checkboxradio-checked', true) // does nothing
$('#chkbox').checkboxradio('option', 'ui-checkboxradio-checked', true) // does nothing
$('#chkbox').checkboxradio('option', 'classes.ui-checkboxradio.ui-checkboxradio-checked', true) // and again, nothing...
```

This is irritating.  Does anyone have a solution to this seemingly simple problem?

Answer (score 6):

I hope it should be help you thanks.

```js
$container = $("<div>")
$container.append($("<label for='chkbox'>"))
$container.append($("<input type='checkbox' id='chkbox' >"))
$container.appendTo("body")
 $("#chkbox").checkboxradio();
$("#chkbox").prop("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh")
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Blank</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any reason why you do not have consistency in your apostrophe? The HTML portion has double apostrophe for attributes, yet the generated HTML from JQuery has single apostrophe.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `change` function as `jquery ui` will change the visual effect on change so only settiing the `checked` property wont take any effect

```
$("#chkbox").attr("checked","checked").change();
```

Comment: There is refresh() method for that widget.
Also, jQuery specs says that you shoud use prop() method for setting properties like checked, selected, or disabled